# Merge attributes from different Chef cookbooks or recipes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, berkshelf

Is there a possibility to merge attributes from several cookbooks or recipes?

What I want to achieve is the following:

**cookbook 1**

sets a default list of attributes
like
       default[:bamboo][:agent][:attributes]                = {
           'system.attr-1'                           => 'test1'
       }

in *template.conf*, I have

```
<% if @options -%>
<%   @options.sort.map do | option, value | -%>
<%= option %>=  <%= value %>
<%   end -%>
<% end -%>
```

**cookbook 2**

inherent "cookbook 1"
and have 2 recipes

recipe1

```
   node.default[:bamboo][:agent][:attributes]                = {
       'system.attr-2'                           => 'test2'
   }
```

recipe2

```
   node.default[:bamboo][:agent][:attributes]                = {
       'system.attr-3'                           => 'test3'
   }
```

Now what I want is that the *template.conf*
from *"cookbook 1"* is updated/merged with the attributes of cookbook2 and those recipes.

Is this possible?  If not, what are the other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cookbook 2, you want to take advantage of Ruby's `Hash#merge`:

```
node.default[:bamboo][:agent][:attributes] = node[:bamboo][:agent][:attributes].merge(
  'system.attr-3' => 'test3'
)
```

And then ensure cookbook 2 depends on cookbook 1 (so the attributes are loaded first).

Comment: but this means i need to a piece of code to each recipe 
to create the template.conf correct?

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this is the most beatifull way to go but got it to work with

```
node.default[:bamboo][:agent][:attributes] = node[:bamboo][:agent][:attributes].merge(
    'system.attr-3' => 'test3'
)

template 'bamboo-capabilities.properties' do
path "#{node[:bamboo][:agent][:data_dir]}/bin/bamboocapabilities.properties"
source 'bamboo-capabilities.properties.erb'
cookbook 'bamboo'
  owner  node[:bamboo][:agent][:user]
  group  node[:bamboo][:agent][:group]
  mode 0644
  variables(
      :options => node[:bamboo][:agent][:attributes]
  )
  notifies :restart, 'service[bamboo-agent]', :delayed
end
```

EDIT::
okay this does create a few problems
because cookbook1 is goint to delete the old entries and when it finally arrives
at cookbook2 recipe 1 it will add the entries again
this causing on each chef-run a restart